# Does anyone know what the git bash program for windows uses for its shell?

Tags: git, github, terminal, cmd

Sorry if this is the wrong place to be posting but I am using the git bash program for windows downloaded from github.

It pretty much functions the same as a linux / mac terminal and I was wondering if there was any software out there that does the same thing?

The problem is that I can only have one git bash window open, if there is a way to open more than 1 instance of git bash, that would be great too!

Thanks a lot,

Martin

Answer (score 9):

[Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) uses a Windows port of [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/) which is provided by the MSYS project which is, in turn, a part of the [MinGW project](http://www.mingw.org/).  As Andrew pointed out, this piece of software is really a part of [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com) which Github for Windows includes and uses internally.

So you can get `bash` for Windows outside of Github for Windows by installing MSYS.

Note though that Git for Windows is based on a *modified* `msys.dll` which received substantial amount of changes not included upstream.  I'm not sure if this constitutes a user-noticeable change but "stock" `bash` might therefore differ in behaviour from that you're using inside Github for Windows.

Also note that this port of `bash` hasn't been taught to properly deal with non-ASCII characters.  Hence even though Git for Windows is full Unicode since 1.7.10, `bash` doesn't know about this and I'm not sure it ever will.

Answer (score 8):

It uses [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com/), a packing containing MSys/MinGW and git. You can get multiple tabs using a wrapper like [console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Comment: Great thanks. Do you know of any guide setting up mysysgit with console? Thanks again!

Comment: Please don't use wrong terminology: "msysgit" is a development evrironment to develop Git for Windows, and "Git for Windows" is what that "Github for Windows" software uses. This distinction is made clear on the [project's website](http://msysgit.github.com/). So please consider editing your answer.

Comment: @kostix So it is - the "msysgit" name reflects the component names and I used MSYS by itself long before I'd used git. I really should have read their page more thoroughly. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Both on Windows 7 and 8 you can shift+left-click the Git icon, in the launchbar or the magical search box, to open another instance.

Alternatively, you can just double-click the shortcut or sh.exe in Git/bin/.

**Note:** Includes improvement from Fergie and botimer.

Comment: Good tip- but it's actually shift+left-click :)

Comment: This also works on Windows 8, as well as in the magical search boxes. For example, Win+S, start typing git, and shift-click or hit shift-enter to launch a new window rather than activating an already-open one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about ["Replacing default git bash console with Console2"](http://buildstarted.com/2012/05/11/replacing-default-git-bash-console-with-console2/) that'll help you.